# The mysql configuration file '/opt/bitnami/mysql/conf/my.cnf' is not writable

Tags: mysql

Now I am using this command to in stall mysql in my kubernetes 1.15:

```
$ helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
$ helm install my-release bitnami/mysql
```

when the mysql stateful sets started, shows this waring:

```
mysql 11:12:23.57 WARN  ==> The mysql configuration file '/opt/bitnami/mysql/conf/my.cnf' is not writable. Configurations based on environment variables will not be applied for this file.
```

and I have changed the mysql root password in kubernetes secrets, and now I did not able to use the new password to login into mysql, what should I do to fix it? I am using this command to login:

```
mycli -h 172.30.184.8 -u mysql -p 9Ve5TEHgcY // way 1
mysql -h localhost -uroot -p 6a4vUXlTyeRvzizZ // way 2
```

shows error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

what should I do to fix the waring? and login into mysql success. This is the stateful sets define:

```
{
  "kind": "StatefulSet",
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1beta2",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "ajidou-mysql",
    "namespace": "dabai-fat",
    "selfLink": "/apis/apps/v1beta2/namespaces/dabai-fat/statefulsets/ajidou-mysql",
    "uid": "894b8cfe-c000-408e-9eee-f0b18eff9aed",
    "resourceVersion": "81999050",
    "generation": 9,
    "creationTimestamp": "2021-04-26T10:11:23Z",
    "labels": {
      "app.kubernetes.io/component": "primary",
      "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "ajidou-mysql",
      "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Helm",
      "app.kubernetes.io/name": "mysql",
      "helm.sh/chart": "mysql-8.5.5"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "meta.helm.sh/release-name": "ajidou-mysql",
      "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": "dabai-fat"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app.kubernetes.io/component": "primary",
        "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "ajidou-mysql",
        "app.kubernetes.io/name": "mysql"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "app.kubernetes.io/component": "primary",
          "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "ajidou-mysql",
          "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Helm",
          "app.kubernetes.io/name": "mysql",
          "helm.sh/chart": "mysql-8.5.5"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "checksum/configuration": "41e7174a05fda333d37a84fdb7a7730102c7036e38fcbacd7567e3d58b3e675e"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "config",
            "configMap": {
              "name": "ajidou-mysql",
              "defaultMode": 420
            }
          }
        ],
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "mysql",
            "image": "docker.io/bitnami/mysql:8.0.24-debian-10-r0",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "mysql",
                "containerPort": 3306,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "BITNAMI_DEBUG",
                "value": "false"
              },
              {
                "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "secretKeyRef": {
                    "name": "ajidou-mysql",
                    "key": "mysql-root-password"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "MYSQL_DATABASE",
                "value": "my_database"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {},
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "data",
                "mountPath": "/bitnami/mysql"
              },
              {
                "name": "config",
                "mountPath": "/opt/bitnami/mysql/conf/my.cnf",
                "subPath": "my.cnf"
              }
            ],
            "livenessProbe": {
              "exec": {
                "command": [
                  "/bin/bash",
                  "-ec",
                  "password_aux=\"${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-}\"\nif [[ -f \"${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE:-}\" ]]; then\n    password_aux=$(cat \"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE\")\nfi\nmysqladmin status -uroot -p\"${password_aux}\"\n"
                ]
              },
              "initialDelaySeconds": 120,
              "timeoutSeconds": 1,
              "periodSeconds": 10,
              "successThreshold": 1,
              "failureThreshold": 3
            },
            "readinessProbe": {
              "exec": {
                "command": [
                  "/bin/bash",
                  "-ec",
                  "password_aux=\"${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-}\"\nif [[ -f \"${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE:-}\" ]]; then\n    password_aux=$(cat \"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE\")\nfi\nmysqladmin status -uroot -p\"${password_aux}\"\n"
                ]
              },
              "initialDelaySeconds": 30,
              "timeoutSeconds": 1,
              "periodSeconds": 10,
              "successThreshold": 1,
              "failureThreshold": 3
            },
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
            "securityContext": {
              "runAsUser": 1001
            }
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "serviceAccountName": "ajidou-mysql",
        "serviceAccount": "ajidou-mysql",
        "securityContext": {
          "fsGroup": 1001
        },
        "affinity": {
          "podAntiAffinity": {
            "preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": [
              {
                "weight": 1,
                "podAffinityTerm": {
                  "labelSelector": {
                    "matchLabels": {
                      "app.kubernetes.io/component": "primary",
                      "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "ajidou-mysql",
                      "app.kubernetes.io/name": "mysql"
                    }
                  },
                  "namespaces": [
                    "dabai-fat"
                  ],
                  "topologyKey": "kubernetes.io/hostname"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "volumeClaimTemplates": [
      {
        "metadata": {
          "name": "data",
          "creationTimestamp": null,
          "labels": {
            "app.kubernetes.io/component": "primary",
            "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "ajidou-mysql",
            "app.kubernetes.io/name": "mysql"
          }
        },
        "spec": {
          "accessModes": [
            "ReadWriteOnce"
          ],
          "resources": {
            "requests": {
              "storage": "8Gi"
            }
          },
          "volumeMode": "Filesystem"
        },
        "status": {
          "phase": "Pending"
        }
      }
    ],
    "serviceName": "ajidou-mysql",
    "podManagementPolicy": "OrderedReady",
    "updateStrategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate"
    },
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 10
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 9,
    "replicas": 1,
    "currentReplicas": 1,
    "updatedReplicas": 1,
    "currentRevision": "ajidou-mysql-f69895f8c",
    "updateRevision": "ajidou-mysql-f69895f8c",
    "collisionCount": 0
  }
}
```

Now I try to reinstall the mysql in kubernetes and use the initial password to login into mysql:

```
$ exec kubectl exec -i -t -n dabai-fat ajidou-mysql-0 -c mysql "--" sh -c "clear; (bash || ash || sh)"                                         ‹ruby-2.7.2›
sh: 1: clear: not found
I have no name!@ajidou-mysql-0:/$ mysql -h 172.30.184.8 -uroot -p F7cVhpiRsC
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.30.184.8' (using password: YES)
I have no name!@ajidou-mysql-0:/$ mysql -h 172.30.184.8 -uroot -p F7cVhpiRsC
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.30.184.8' (using password: YES)
I have no name!@ajidou-mysql-0:/$ mysql -h 172.30.184.8 -uroot -p F7cVhpiRsC
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.30.184.8' (using password: YES)
I have no name!@ajidou-mysql-0:/$
```

the UI shows error:

```
Readiness probe failed: mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)' Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

[image]

Comment: see: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws-templates/apps/wordpress/administration/reset-password/ ?

Comment: or: https://docs.bitnami.com/ibm/infrastructure/mysql/administration/change-reset-password/

Comment: But there are also a lot of question about changing password in MySQL on SO.

Comment: I reinstall mysql and using the initial password stiil could not login into mysql @Luuk

Comment: I do not want to change password, I just want to login into mysql @Luuk I also could using the initial password and now login into seems impossible